# How to deploy java 17 lambda function through cloud formation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, java-17

I'm planning to deploy java 17 function to AWS lambda. But since as per the documentation AWS didn't provide a bas image for java 17.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java.html

So I have a problem with what value should I use in cloudformation template `Runtime` field

```
"AMIIDLookup": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "Properties": {
        "Handler": "index.handler",
        "Role": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "LambdaExecutionRole",
                "Arn"
            ]
        },
        "Code": {
            "S3Bucket": "lambda-functions",
            "S3Key": "amilookup.zip"
        },
        "Runtime": "Java11",  # what is the alternative for this
        "Timeout": 25,
        "TracingConfig": {
            "Mode": "Active"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [no official Java17 runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) for Lambda yet, you would have to create a [custom runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html) on your own.

Comment: It's not quite the same as a runtime, but I manage a set of publicly-available custom AWS Lambda base images for Java 17, 18, and 19 published at https://gallery.ecr.aws/aleph0io/lambda/java and https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/aleph0io/aws-lambda-java. They work great for AWS Lambda functions packaged as Docker images. Source code available at https://github.com/aleph0io/aws-lambda-java-base-images for the curious.

Answer (score 0):

Robert is right, either create a custom runtime or use docker image to spin up your aws lambda function https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/aws-cvo-blg-aws-lambda-images-how-to-use-container-images-to-deploy-lambda

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There will be an officially managed Java17 runtime from 2023-05-29 on.
See github: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/issues/29#issuecomment-1472890683

EDIT: Java 17 is already available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Answer (score 0):

A Java 17 Lambda runtime is now available: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/aws-lambda-java-17/